# UITextField: change appearance for disabled textfields

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, uitextfield

I'd like to change the appearance of disabled textfields, i.e. text and background color - is there an easy and legal way to achieve this?

Comment: Easiest way will be either subclass UITextField or create category on UITextField

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could subclass your UITextfield and overwrite the `enabled` property like this

```
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    [super setEnabled:enabled];
    // Do your customization here, eg:
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Swift version:

```
override var isEnabled: Bool {
    willSet {
        backgroundColor = newValue ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, works perfect. Just wanted to know if there is a 'built in' solution, but this is simple enough :)

Comment: there's `disabledBackground` property, but it didn't worked for me unless I also set `background` property on `UITextField`

Answer (score 2):

As for only appearance, the `UITextField` class has a property named `disabledBackground` that takes a `UIImage` object as the background image when it is disabled. Similarly, the `background` property is used for other cases.